# How to compile Kibana 6 .less files to single .css file using lessc

Tags: css, less, kibana

I am trying to compile Kibana's .less files into a single css file.

[Kibana 6 Less files @ github](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/tree/master/src/ui/public/styles)

I already tried to use lessc.

But I don't know which file needs to be passed initially to lessc. All .less files seem to be linked against each other, so I believe it should be possible out of the box to build a single .css file.

Can anyone guide me into the right direction? I am totally new to working with less.

Comment: *II am trying to compile Kibana's .less files into a single css file.* - Are they supposed to be compiled that way at all? From code base it looks like a (less or more modular) library of styles (with each "module" to be used at will, e.g. with `webpack` for example)  rather than a monolithic stylesheet of predefined structure. *I am totally new to working with less* - it's more a matter of the Kibana documentation rather than Less (language or tools) knowledge.

Comment: your oberservation is correct. These are loaded within an angular app I believe. Do you think there is an easy way to extract at least the styles to compile a css that works with bootstrap?

Comment: Just create "my-kibana.less" file, put there imports of the modules of interest and compile (note though they're using their own copy of bootstrap so some things may be incompatble). The rest depends only what exactly and why exactly you're going to do (as usual).